# Force Close ListView in Android

Tags: android, mysql, listview

when I run my emulator it just force close here is the logcat shows......

```
07-16 03:12:30.536: D/AndroidRuntime(386): Shutting down VM
07-16 03:12:30.536: W/dalvikvm(386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception             (group=0x4001d800)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.database_demo/com.database_demo.Database_demo}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.database_demo.Database_demo.onCreate(Database_demo.java:40)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-16 03:12:30.556: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  ... 11 more
```

my java code

```
package com.database_demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Database_demo extends ListActivity {
ListView list;
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;;
StringBuilder sb = null;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    items.add("Employ");

    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.2/ListView/wa.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValue=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //Convert response to string  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //END Convert response to string  
    String Cat;
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               Cat=json_data.getString("category");
               items.add("Category: " + Cat);
           }
        setupList();
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
private void setupList(){
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
}
}
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: inside  `R.layout.main` you have to declara a ListView with id `@android:id/list`

Comment: tanx it helped me but I didnt see the datas yet here is the logcat says `07-16 03:35:33.409: I/global(335): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.`

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

```
<ListView
 android:id="@android:id/list" // must be there is xml
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

`ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. To do this, **your own view MUST contain a `ListView` object with the id "`@android:id/list`"** (or list if it's in code)

Comment: tanx it helped me but I didnt see the datas yet here is the logcat says `07-16 03:35:33.409: I/global(335): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.`

Comment: @Ørly there seems to lot of mistakes. You are doing network related operation on the ui thread whihc is not possible post honeycomb. You should use a thread or asynctask

Comment: it's difficult to say everything at once. post a new question as and when you find it difficult.

Comment: I change the line from:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));`
to this:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"), 8192);`
It remove the meessage

but another came out from logcat

`07-16 04:22:47.098: I/AndroidRuntime(495): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed`

Comment: @Ørly post a new question on stackoverflow there are many mistakes which can't be addressed in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending ListActivity. That means that layout main.xml must contain listview with android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: tanx it helped me but I didnt see the datas yet here is the logcat says `07-16 03:35:33.409: I/global(335): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the xml of list view

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Since you are using ListActivity your xml file must specify the keyword android while mentioning to a ID.

If you need a custom ListView then instead of Extending a ListActivity, you have to simply extend an Activity and should have the same id without the keyword android.

Comment: tanx it helped me but I didnt see the datas yet here is the logcat says `07-16 03:35:33.409: I/global(335): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

to

```
list = getListView();
```

//or write

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

> and in your **layout XML** for the listView id use

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: tanx it helped me but I didnt see the datas yet here is the logcat says

`07-16 03:35:33.409: I/global(335): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
`